# How should I test a field against an SQL variable which can be null?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, three-valued-logic

I've got the following SQL :

```
CREATE TABLE tbFoo(
    a varchar(50) NULL,
) 


CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_tbFoo_a ON tbFoo
(
    a ASC
)
WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON)

insert into tbFoo select null
insert into tbFoo select 'test'
```

The two following queries work fine and use my index as expected :

```
select * from tbFoo where a='test'
select * from tbFoo where a is null
```

Now, let's pretend I want to store my comparison value in a variable, like this :

```
declare @a varchar(50)
select @a = NULL
```

The following query won't return the expected results if @a is null because I should use the "is" operator rather than "="

```
select * from tbFoo where a=@a
```

The following will work but will do a table scan if @a is null (because of the 'test' row which forces the evaluation of the second parenthesis)

```
select * from tbFoo where (a is null and @a is null) or (a=@a)
```

Eventually, I've came up with this solution, which works fine and uses my index :

```
select * from tbFoo where (a is null and @a is null) or (@a is not null and a=@a)
```

Is my analysis of the situation correct?

Is there a better way to handle this situation ?

Answer (score 3):

> Eventually, I came up with this solution, which works fine and uses my index :

In SQL Server 2008, you can define a filtered index based on a predicate that excludes NULLs:

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_tbFoo_a 
ON tbFoo (a)
WHERE a IS NOT NULL;
```

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is ever "equal to" NULL... which is sort of the point of NULL.

Your solution will work fine. I'm surprised at how the query optimizer handles the shorter version. I would think that testing a for NULL before testing equality with a table scan would be a no-brainer.

Comment: @Guiness: good point! But in the sense of database *theory*, NULL is just NULL, even if the RDBMS lets you fudge that. For maximum maintainability, I think the OP's solution is preferable in most cases to forcing the database into a non-standard mode. Maybe if he was doing a few dozen similar comparisons within the same stored procedure, the pendulum would swing the opposite direction.

Answer (score 1):

another possibility is using setting ansi nulls to off

```
set ansi_nulls off

declare @a varchar(50)
select @a = NULL

select * from tbFoo where a=@a

set ansi_nulls on
```

Just keep in mind that you are breaking away from the default behavior here

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps your database engine optimizes what you've got automatically, but it seems to me like the following would be more efficient:

```
if @a IS NULL
    select * from tbFoo where a is null
else
    select * from tbFoo where a = @a
```

My reasoning for this is that you would perform the `if @a IS NULL` condition only once, rather than checking it for every line in the database.  Again, though, a quality database engine should be able to convert your code into the same kind of data plan as this.

Answer (score 0):

This what I do.  It's very flexible.
I am assuming that @a is an argument for the sproc. 'somethingweird' can be something that you will never see in your recordset '~~~' or whatever.

```
set @a = isnull(@a,'somethingweird')
select * from tbFoo where isnull(a,'somethingweird')=@a
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an instance at home to play with, but I can see the table scan getting very annoying.  A possible alternative is to use UNION in place of the OR operator...

```
select * from tbFoo where (a is null and @a is null)
UNION ALL
select * from tbFoo where (a=@a and @a is not null)
```

(I'm not sure exactly what effect the "@a is not null" will have on performance, but my gut feel would be to include it.  It's a constant expression that should allow the optimiser to know when the whole condition always fails.  My technique is always to play and see what works best.)

I find this UNION trick to have two properties:
- It can significantly improve performance by simplfying queries
- It balloons code with multiple joins and cause major maintenance headaches

But then, life is jus a balancing act :)

Answer (score 0):

Just ISNULL both sides like so...

```
DECLARE @random VARCHAR(50)
SELECT  @random = 'text that never appears in your table'

SELECT * FROM @tbFoo WHERE ISNULL(a, @random) = ISNULL(@a, @random)
```

Comment: I don't think this will use the indexes effectively. NULL and non-null values can be matched much more efficiently using an index than coalescing them to a constant and then comparing them.

Answer (score 0):

Your analysis is correct - and is why 3-valued logic makes life difficult.

The suggestion from @StriplingWarrior is good; it finesses the problem by executing different SQL depending on whether the variable is null or not.  Where that is not possible, your long-winded solution which repeatedly uses the host variable is necessary.